# Implementation of GUI in main program. (Buttons not working)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am working on a library system class with different methods implementing with GUI.

I successfully made all text fields and buttons etc.

Now, problem is that buttons are not working.

Either there's some problem with making objects of both classes or there's something different with taking action events from TabbedPane that I can't figure out.

Here is a sample of my code. Didn't put all code because that's too long.

public class RunProgram extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
private static final int WIDTH = 400;
private static final int HEIGHT = 430;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_DIGITS = 30;
private long accessionNumber = 1001;

LibrarySystem ITLib = new LibrarySystem(); //object of LibrarySystem class  to be able to use methods in actionListener method.
```

public RunProgram() { //Constructor

```
    setTitle("Welcome to Library");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Container container = getContentPane();
    JTabbedPane Pane = new JTabbedPane();
```

........

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
    switch (actionCommand) {
        case "Add Book":
            String t = title.getText();
            String a1 = author1.getText();
            String a2 = author2.getText();
            String p = publisher.getText();
            int py = stringToInt(yop.getText());
            String isbn = ISBN.getText();

            Book newBook = new Book(t, a1, a2, p, py, isbn, accessionNumber);
            if (ITLib.addBook(newBook)) {
                title.setText("Book added successfully.");
                aNum.setText(Long.toString(accessionNumber));
                accessionNumber++;
            } else
                title.setText("Book already exists!");
            break;
        case "Delete Book": {
            long an = stringToLong(aNum.getText());
            if (ITLib.deleteBook(an))
                aNum.setText("Book deleted successfully.");
            else
                aNum.setText("Book doesn't exist!");
            break; }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    RunProgram RLibrary = new RunProgram();
    RLibrary.setVisible(true);
}
```

Please help. (PS. I'm just a beginner and we didn't do much about protecting codes so most coding is in direct methods.)

Comment: post your code, not links to screenshots. Also: show the code where you add the actionListeners to your buttons.

Comment: If you add your actual codes instead of screenshots, people can try your codes and maybe modifiy them. Please insert your codes.

Comment: you must put the source code instead of images, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Debug, set a break point (clicking in the margin), to see whether the code is reached there and what variables contain. And `actionPerformed` happens on the event handling thread; so one cannot expect redraws there when changing other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should setActionCommand on each button and then add ActionListener

```
public class RunProgram extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   public RunProgram () {
      // to do logic to initialise
      initComponents();
   }
   public void initComponents() {
       JButton addbook = new JButton("Add Book");
       addbook.setActionCommand("Add Book");
       addbook.addActionListener(this);

      // add code to initialise button and add them to correct tabbed pane
   }
 }
```

Comment: It worked like this. But what was the exact problem here? Because in my other GUI programs I never setActionCommand

Comment: because in other program you may use per button one action listener or you might have used if condition with ae.getSource() to identify which button click in case of using same actionlistener for multiple button.